# Regarding NTRU homomorphic properties

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, ntru

NTRU has some homomorphic properties modulo q, supporting both addition and multiplication. Due to its nature, it cannot support many of them. My main focus currently is in the addition, so the question is how many additions could it support to consider the result reliable? I believe that a naive bound would be $q/2$ but is there anything better?

Comment: Maybe that's covered in this paper: [López-Alt et al. "On-the-fly multiparty computation on the cloud via multikey fully homomorphic encryption" (2012)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/094.pdf)

Comment: It would be better if you specify first which version of NTRU are you talking about. Is it the "regular" NTRU or the provably-secure version from Stehlé and Steinfeld?

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the proposed paper. You are right about your comment, as there are many flavors. I had in mind the LWE variant of Stehlé and Steinfeld, but any other would work as well.

Comment: In that case, then it would depend ultimately in the choice of parameters $(n, \alpha, \sigma,$ etc).

Comment: Well to be honest I had the following in mind:
Let $c_i=hs_i+pe_i+m_i$ then $\sum c_i=\sum hs_i+pe_i+m_i$.
Therefore, if you want to be able to decrypt it, we need $||h\sum s_i+p\sum s_i +\sum m_i||_\infty<q/2$. Since the coeffs of the "random noise" as well as the message are picked from {-1,0,1} we could say that they are equidistributed so we could expect that they contribute q/6 in each case at most (VERY ROUGHLY speaking--using worst case scenario). Therefore, I would expect to allow at most something in the $q/3$ additions, which is independent of these params...

Comment: You have the correctness condition wrong. It should be $||f\cdot \Sigma c_i||_{\infty} < q/2$.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right... I will have another look on it. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Since you referring to the LWE variant of Stehlé and Steinfeld, I will try to give you an answer to your question in that context. Note that these results are a mere extension of the correctness condition in Lemma 3.7 from the [revised version](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/004) of the paper [SS13]. As I said in the comments, at the end it all depends on the choice of parameters ($n, \alpha, q$, etc), and additionally, on the number of additions you want to support.

In this scheme, ciphertexts are of the form $c = h s + p e + m$, where $h$ is the public key, $s$ and $e$ are sampled from a Gaussian distribution, $p$ is a public parameter, and $m$ is the message. Public keys are of the form $h = p g f^{-1}$, where $f$ is the secret key, and $g$ a random polynomial.

The correctness condition for one ciphertext is $||f \cdot c_i ||_{\infty} \leq q/2$. We want to check the conditions for decrypting correctly a sum of $k$ ciphertexts:

$c_{sum} = \sum\limits^k_{i=1} c_i = \sum\limits^k_{i=1}(h s_i + p e_i + m_i)$

Since $f h = f (p g f^{-1}) = p g$, then $f \cdot c_i = f h s_i + p f e + f M = p g s_i + p f e + f M$

Hence, we want to check whether $||f \cdot c_{sum} ||_{\infty} \leq q/2$, where:

$f \cdot c_{sum} = \sum\limits^k_{i=1}(p g s_i + p f e_i + f m_i) = \sum\limits^k_{i=1}p g s_i + \sum\limits^k_{i=1}p f e_i + \sum\limits^k_{i=1}f m_i$

Lemma 3.7 provides the following bounds:

$||pgs_i||_{\infty}, ||pfe_i||_{\infty} \leq 8 \alpha q n^{0.25} \omega(\log n)||p||^2 \sigma$

$||fM||_{\infty} \leq 4n||p||^2 \sigma$

Therefore, $||f \cdot c_{sum}||_{\infty} \leq 2k\cdot(8 \alpha q n^{0.25} \omega(\log n)||p||^2 \sigma) + 4n||p||^2 \sigma$.

Next, assuming that $n^{0.75} \leq \alpha q$, as in Lemma 3.7, we have that:

$||f \cdot c_{sum}||_{\infty} \leq 16 k \alpha q n^{0.25} \omega(\log n)||p||^2 \sigma + 4n^{0.25}\alpha q||p||^2 \sigma$

After some simplifications, we obtain the following bound:

$||f \cdot c_{sum}||_{\infty} \leq (16 k + 4) n^{0.25}\alpha q\omega(\log n)||p||^2 \sigma$

Note that when $k=1$, it produces precisely the same result than Lemma 3.7. Finally, similarly to Lemma 3.7, we have to initially assume that $ \omega( n^{0.25}\log n)\alpha q k ||p||^2 \sigma < 1$, so the correctness condition for the sum of $k$ ciphertexts holds.

A final note: these results, as the one from Lemma 3.7, are not tight, and depend heavily on the choice of parameters. My guess is that you can sum (much) more than $k$ ciphertexts, and still decrypt correctly.

**References**

[SS13] Stehlé, D., & Steinfeld, R. (2013). Making NTRUEncrypt and NTRUSign as Secure as Standard Worst-Case Problems over Ideal Lattices. IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive, 2013, 4.