# Is there a partially homomorphic quantum secure public key cryptosystem with IND-CCA1 security?

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, post-quantum-cryptography, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I recentely asked ["IND-CCA1 RSA padding?"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27432/23623) about whether there is a IND-CCA1 secure variant of RSA. The original version of the question also allowed usage of ECC which would allow usage of ElGamal, providing IND-CPA and [somewhat IND-CCA1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26882/23623).

Now I have the same setting as in the above question, meaning I need a cryptosystem with some homomorphic property and maximal security notion (IND-CCA1 would be optimal, but IND-CPA would also be OK). But this time I'm asking for a post-quantum scheme having a homomorphic property and being IND-CCA1 secure.

So finally the question:
**Is there any post-quantum public key encryption algorithm providing IND-CCA1/CPA security *and* a partial homomorphic property?**

Please exclude fully homomorphic encryption schemes from the answers. [I know most of them are PQ safe,](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/27589/23623) but they're too slow. And of course please also exclude schemes being *even slower* than FHE schemes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially any IND-CPA-secure lattice-based cryptosystem offers additive homomorphism, up to a predetermined number of operations.

I don't know of any IND-CCA1-secure post-quantum candidate that offers any homomorphic property, except Loftus-May-Smart-Vercauteren SAC'11, which is based on a nonstandard "knowledge of error" lattice assumption.

Comment: At first I thought that your CCA1-secure scheme from EUROCRYPT 2012 may be additively homomorphic, but then I realized that the tag matrices $\mathbf H$ are random for each ciphertext, so it doens't work straightaway. Is it possible to fix these matrices without impacting security? Also, I don't know if the encoding of the messages is homomorphic too.

Comment: Now that I see it, you mention in your paper the possibility of setting $\mathbf H = \mathbf I$. In that case, and given that it seems that the encoding is additively homomorphic too, then this scheme could be an example of CCA1-secure lattice-based PKE that is additively homomorphic.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the CCA1 proof breaks down entirely if you fix the tag matrices to be the same for all ciphertexts. The simulator needs to produce a challenge ciphertext at the tag on which the public key is "punctured," and needs decryption queries need to have different tags so the simulator can decrypt them.  Also, I *suspect* that the scheme is actually *insecure* under CCA1 for the usual reasons, but haven't verified carefully.

Answer (score 2):

There should be plenty of them. Off the top of my head, I'm thinking of the provable secure version of NTRU by Stehlé and Steinfeld [1], which is IND-CPA secure. In this scheme, ciphertexts are of the form:

\begin{equation}
 c = pk \cdot s + p\cdot e + \operatorname{encode}(m)
\end{equation}

where $s$ and $e$ are random polynomials, $p$ is a small prime, and $pk$ is the public key. It can be shown that this scheme is additively homomorphic:
\begin{equation}
 c + c' = pk \cdot (s+s') + p\cdot (e+e') + \operatorname{encode}(m + m')
\end{equation}

In fact, this cryptosystem has been used as the basis of some fully homomorphic encryption schemes, such as [2].

In the response to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/regarding-ntru-homomorphic-properties/24693#24693) I precisely tackle with the correctness condition for the addition of ciphertexts in this cryptosystem.

**References**

[1] Stehlé, D., & Steinfeld, R. (2011). Making NTRU as secure as worst-case problems over ideal lattices. In Advances in Cryptology–EUROCRYPT 2011 (pp. 27-47). Springer Berlin Heidelberg.

[2] López-Alt, A., Tromer, E., & Vaikuntanathan, V. (2012, May). On-the-fly multiparty computation on the cloud via multikey fully homomorphic encryption. In Proceedings of the forty-fourth annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing (pp. 1219-1234). ACM.